# Finding the property value in generic c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a property of a class in a generic method.

```
Class abc
-property Name : xyz
```

I have a method like :

```
public bool findItem<T> (IEnumerable<T> items) where T : Data
{
   if (typeof(T) == typeof(abc))
   {
       // Code comes inside the loop here
       // how to find something like items.First().xyz
   }
}
```

I want to find the property value for the first item but it doesnt work (there is no autosuggest too).

While debugging (in immediate window), I can see my object with class Name when i do `items.First()`.

I tried `items.First()["xyz"]` but doesnt work. `(Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type T)`

Comment: What about `if (items is IEnumerable<abc> abcItems){...}` ?

Comment: You already have a type constraint (`where T : Data`) on your generic method. So you can access all methods and properties of `Data` at *compile time*. Maybe you can add the index operator to this base class / interface? Otherwise you need a check at *runtime* either via `is` operator, strategy pattern with Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>` or reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly could do something like this:

```
public bool FindItem<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    if (items is IEnumerable<Abc> abcs)
    {
        int first = abcs.First().Xyz;
        return true;
    }
    else if (items is IEnumerable<Def> defs)
    {
        int first = defs.First().Ghi;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, that's not the normal way to do it. Normally you'd just use overloads:

```
public bool FindItem(IEnumerable<Abc> items)
{
    int first = items.First().Xyz;
    return true;
}

public bool FindItem(IEnumerable<Def> items)
{
    int first = items.First().Ghi;
    return true;
}
```